# Can RoleProvider be used without MembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider

I would like to use RoleProvider in my application so that I can use the AuthorizeAttribute on my controller actions like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

However, I don't need (and don't want to use) a MembershipProvider as most of the authentication code has already been built in our ASP.net 4.5 web application.

So can I simply use a custom RoleProvider without using/implementing an out-of-the-box MembershipProvider or custom MembershipProvider and be able to use the AuthorizeAttribute?

Thank you.

Comment: ***Answer is Yes.*** However, how do you authenticate an user in existing application? Do you use FormAuthenciation, and hand-roll IPrincipal object yourself? Please post the some codes so that we can suggest how to create RoleProvider based on our implementation.

Comment: We use FormAuthentication like `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)` but don't do anything with iPrincipal. Do we need to extend IPrincipal in place of a MemebershipProvider implementation?